# ffmpeg multiple outputs is working only on the first rtmp

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, rtmp

I have try stream with ffmpeg with output to differents rtmp servers like that

```
ffmpeg -re -i nameoffile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 -strict -2 -f flv \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.1.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.2.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.3.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.4.com/code \
-f flv rtmp://rtmp.5.com/code \
```

The problem is... is working only the first one but not the others

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the output options for each output: `-vcodec libx264 -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100`

Comment: i found this -filter_complex '[0:v]yadif,split=3[out1][out2][out3]' but i have not really understood how to use in my code